In Google Earth Engine get an attribute value from a FeatureCollection and use it as a parameter to Export toDrive
I am trying to extract attribute values from a Feature Collection in Google Earth Engine and use that value as a parameter value afterward.
In the example below, I define the FeatureCollection on the fly. However, in reality, I have the FC as an asset; the idea is to use it as a configuration file. Maybe there is a better way to do this.
The following code works; however, I can only get one attribute now, the 'PROJ' attribute.
How would I extract the 'NAMEUNIT' and use it as a description to Export the result?
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-3.982054891721716, 40.51882898775919],
          [-3.982054891721716, 40.26256975598024],
          [-3.193785848752966, 40.26256975598024],
          [-3.193785848752966, 40.51882898775919]]], null, false);


// Load your Feature Collection
var provinces = ee.FeatureCollection([ee.Feature(null, {NAMEUNIT: 'Madrid', PROJ: 'EPSG:32630'}), 
                        ee.Feature(null, {NAMEUNIT: 'Barcelona', PROJ: 'EPSG:32631'}), 
                        ee.Feature(null, {NAMEUNIT: 'Sevilla', PROJ: 'EPSG:32629'})]);

// Filter the Feature Collection for the province of Madrid
var madridFeature = provinces.filter(ee.Filter.eq('NAMEUNIT', 'Madrid')).first();

// Extract the epsg_code property
var proj = madridFeature.get('PROJ');

// Load the image you want to export (replace with your image)
var image = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA").filterBounds(geometry)

var projValueGlobal;

// Use evaluate() to retrieve the value on the client side
proj.evaluate(function(projValue) {
  projValueGlobal = projValue;  // Store the value in the global variable
  print('Projection for Madrid (inside callback):', projValueGlobal);
  
  // Define the export task
  // I need to do it inside the projValue function; otherwise, it does not work
  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: image,
    description: 'Exported_Image_Madrid',
    scale: 30, // Adjust the scale as needed
    region: geometry,
    crs: projValueGlobal, // Use the extracted EPSG code
    maxPixels: 1e13 // Adjust max pixels if necessary
  });
});

If instead,  I do the following:
// Filter the Feature Collection for the province of Madrid
var madridFeature = provinces.filter(ee.Filter.eq('NAMEUNIT', 'Madrid')).first();

// Extract the epsg_code property
var proj = madridFeature.get('PROJ');

Export.image.toDrive({
    image: image,
    description: 'Exported_Image_Madrid',
    scale: 30, // Adjust the scale as needed
    region: geometry,
    crs: proj, // Use the extracted EPSG code
    max pixel: 1e13 // Adjust max pixels if necessary
});

I get the following problem when exporting the result, see the CRS value:


It looks like this is a case when you can use .getInfo():  inside Export    "description: 'Exported_Image_'+madridFeature.get('NAMEUNIT').getInfo()," But since it's generally not recommended https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-date-getinfo, there might be a better option!

You can look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/484943/154371 for some ideas.
